# jQuery drying up function

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, refactoring, dry

As you can see below, I clearly repeat myself over. I understand that this is bad practice.

So, how can the 4 duplicate lines of code within the if and else statement be refactored into one?

Some guidance toward better practice would be greatly appreciated. Also, any DRY references / tutorials that you found helpful in learning this technique.

```
$('.inner_wrap .details').click(function() {
    var index = $('.inner_wrap .details').index(this);

    $('.details').removeClass('here');
    $(this).addClass('here');
    $('.view').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.view').addClass('active');
    console.log(index);
    if(index > 2){
        index -= 3;
        **// This and its corresponding else statement is the topic of the question**
        $(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide').removeClass('tabShow');
        $(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('tabShow');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide').removeClass('tabShow');
        $(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('tabShow');
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: specified the question in post. if/else statement has some repetition. Looking to condense it.

Comment: why do you need to do the class swapping in the conditional? surely you only need the if for the index correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(index > 2){ index -= 3; }
**// This and its corresponding else statement is the topic of the question**
$(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper')
       .find('.tabSlide').removeClass('tabShow')
       .eq(index).addClass('tabShow')
```

Ditch the else, since you're executing that code regardless you don't need to include it in the statement. You can just keep working on the chain, also, since you're first targeting all elements with class `tabSlide` and then targeting just a specific instance of that class based on its index.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the code is repeated in both `if` and `else`, meaning, it's always executed. Just take it out of the statement:

```
if (index > 2) {
    index -= 3;
}
var elt = $(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper');
elt.find('.tabSlide').removeClass('tabShow');
elt.find('.tabSlide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('tabShow');
```

Next, note that the jQuery object is just an array. You can simplify your code thus:

```
if (index > 2) {
    index -= 3;
}
var elt = $(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide');
$(elt.removeClass('tabShow')[index]).addClass('tabShow');
```

Finally, we can eliminate the aux variable, used just to demonstrate how you call the same object:

```
if (index > 2) {
    index -= 3;
}
$($(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide').removeClass('tabShow')[index]).addClass('tabShow');
```

Please, break this into more than one line of code :D

[EDIT]

OK, and just for fun, here's an even more extreme astronaut-type code, getting rid of the remaining `if`:

```
$($(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide').removeClass('tabShow')[(index <= 2 ? index : index - 3)]).addClass('tabShow');
```

BUT! It's awfully unreadable and IMO, you should stick with just the first step. Until it becomes a performance issue, don't overdo it. Applying the DRY rule at the cost of readability/maintainability or just sticking everything into a single line of code makes as much sense as reading & writing minified code. Ie, don't do it :).

[EDIT 2]

@StuartNelson reminded me of the existence of the `$.eq()` function, which would bring the final code to this (broken into several lines):

```
$(this).closest('.outer_wrapper')
    .prev('.outer_wrapper')
    .find('.tabSlide')
    .removeClass('tabShow')
    .eq(index <= 2 ? index : index - 3)
    .addClass('tabShow');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `index` only using the `if` statement and you could keep a variable for the jQuery element used:

```
$('.inner_wrap .details').click(function() {
    var index = $('.inner_wrap .details').index(this);

    $('.details').removeClass('here');
    $(this).addClass('here');
    $('.view').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.view').addClass('active');
    console.log(index);
    if(index > 2){
       index -= 3;
    }
    var element = $(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper');
    element.find('.tabSlide').removeClass('tabShow');
    element.find('.tabSlide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('tabShow');   
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Those two lines are executed last in both the if and else clause, so they can be pulled out of both and put after the entire if/else statement:

```
if(index > 2){
    index -= 3;
}

$(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide').removeClass('tabShow');
$(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('tabShow');
```

This rule is always true. If they were the first two lines in both your if and else clause you would pull them out and put them before your if statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since all you really care about is setting the index, that is the only thing you need in the if staement, the rest can go out:

```
if(index > 2){
    index -= 3;
}

$(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide').removeClass('tabShow');
$(this).closest('.outer_wrapper').prev('.outer_wrapper').find('.tabSlide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('tabShow');
```